# Как сменить порт для OnlyOffice

Tags: onlyoffice

Я установил OnlyOffice и по умолчанию он слушает 80 порт. Как сменить его на другой? на 80 порту у меня висят сайты. Или как сделать, что бы он открывался, например, по адресу office.site.com. Система - Debian 8

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть будет достаточно `/etc/nginx/conf.d/onlyoffice-documentserver.conf` заменить порт на другой в директиве `listen`.

Было:

```
listen 80;
```

Стало:

```
listen 8080;
```

По второй части: для этого нужно настроить проксирование запросов через nginx, что хорошо раскрыто в сети.

Comment: оказалось, что он у меня не стал, выдает ошибку

    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @Diefair это ошибка относится к MySQL и заслуживает отдельного вопроса; если мой ответ вам помог - примите его, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы устанавливали `ONLYOFFICE` из `.deb` пакета, достаточно будет поменять порт в настройках `nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/onlyoffice)`.